# Instead of trigger value of virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have view created from a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee_list AS
    SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastName AS "employee"
    FROM employees;
END;
```

And I want to insert values into this view. I created INSTEAD OF trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_v_emp_list
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON employee_list
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.employee);
END;
```

But when I'm trying to compile this trigger I get error:

```
Error(3,24): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.EMPLOYEE'
```

Is there a possibility to get this inserted value in trigger for insert this value into employees table? Of course I will split this value into two separated values.

Comment: Try removing the double quotes in the view definition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"employee"` made it case sensitive. 
When you wrote :new.employee it tried to look for uppercase. Same thing happens with aliases. Should make it work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee_list AS
    SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastName AS employee
    FROM employees;
END;
```

Comment: It's tagged as Oracle SQL.